# Angular 4, Typescrypt Bitcoin Currency Exchange - The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

Tags: angular, typescript, bitcoin

Im trying to create a currency exchange app in Angular 4 but I have a problem when I change one of the property values. Let me explain myself:

I have a service that get the Bitcoin price in Chilean Pesos (CLP) from an API Service and then it store the price in an Interface. What I'm trying to do is that when the user types certain amount of CLP, the app automatically convert it to BTC.
When I created the algorithm to do this I used the property with a random number just to test it.

Component.ts:

```
  exchangeRate : 715000;
  targetAmount = 1;
  baseAmount = this.exchangeRate;

  update(baseAmount) {
    this.targetAmount = parseFloat(baseAmount) / this.exchangeRate;
  }
```

and this is the DOM:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Monto en CLP</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Ingrese el monto en CLP" (input)="update($event.target.value)">
</div>
```

This worked properly but then I added some code lines to get exchangeRate from the API Service. This is the code:

Component.ts

```
minask(price: SurbtcMarketView): number {
        return price.min_ask;
    }
```

Interface.ts

```
  export class SurbtcMarket {
  public ticker: SurbtcMarketView;
}

export class SurbtcMarketView {
  public last_price : number;
  public min_ask : number;
  public max_bid : number;
  public volume : number;
  public price_variation_24h : number;
  public price_variation_7d : number;
}
```

Now I want to use minask instead of 715000 in exchangeRate like this:

```
exchangeRate : this.minask;
  targetAmount = 1;
  baseAmount = this.exchangeRate;

  update(baseAmount) {
    this.targetAmount = parseFloat(baseAmount) / this.exchangeRate;
  }
```

in / this.exchangeRate; I get this error:

> The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type

How can I avoid this? Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

This is the service where I get the data to use in this.exchangeRate:

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { SurbtcMarket } from './surbtcmarket'


@Injectable()
export class SurbtcService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public getPricess() :Observable<SurbtcMarket> {
    return this.http.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.minask` references a method, not an atomic value (e.g. number). That's why you are getting the error. Convert this to

```
this.minask($YOUR_ARGUMENT)
```

Demo usage in your component code:

```
demoStockViewInstance = {
  last_price : 10;
  min_ask : 5;
  max_bid : 10;
  volume : 10;
  price_variation_24h : 10;
  price_variation_7d : 10;
}
// exchange should contain value 5 
exchangeRate = this.minask(this.demoStockViewInstance);
targetAmount = 1;
baseAmount = this.exchangeRate;

update(baseAmount) {
 this.targetAmount = parseFloat(baseAmount) / this.exchangeRate;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If the service returns an observable, you should perform the calculation inside its `subscribe` callback in your component code:

```
this.surbtcService.getPricess().subscribe(response => {
  demoStockViewInstance = response.min_ask
})
```

Comment: Thanks or your reply @SALEH I did it like this:

 exchangeRate = this.minask(this.SurbtcMarketView);
  targetAmount = 1;
  baseAmount = this.exchangeRate;

but now I get this error:
[ts] Property 'SurbtcMarketView' does not exist on type 'RecibirpagoComponent'.

Comment: Thats because `SurbtcMarketView ` is not a property of your component named `RecibirpagoComponent `. Change the name to a valid instance of the component, like the example  `demoStockViewInstance`

Comment: Sorry SALEH but I'm just learning and I did not understand what you said and probably I did not explain myself properly.

I created a service and I get the data prices from there. If I use your example then I'll be using any exchange rate and not the one from my service.

I edited the thread and added service.ts

I'm really sorry to bother. Thanks again.

Comment: If I add that to my component I get an error saying that SurbtcService is not a property of my component.

Comment: declare it as a parameter of your `constructor` method. Like:
`constructor(private SurbtcService: SurbtcService)` in your component file